# conflict using both locale and night mode change in AndroidX

Tags: android, localization, locale, androidx, android-night-mode

I tried to use night mode with changing locale in app (with version of appcompat:1.1.0 and appcompat:1.2.0 ) but when activity start again no changes were implement for locale .  here is my code

```
  @Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
    super.attachBaseContext(updateBaseContextLocale(base));
}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
private Context updateResourcesLocale(Context context, Locale locale) {
    Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    configuration.setLocale(locale);
    return context.createConfigurationContext(configuration);
}
private Context updateBaseContextLocale(Context context) {
    String language = LocaleHelper.getLanguage(context); // Helper method to get saved language from SharedPreferences
    Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        return updateResourcesLocale(context, locale);
    }

    return updateResourcesLocaleLegacy(context, locale);
}
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private Context updateResourcesLocaleLegacy(Context context, Locale locale) {
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    Configuration configuration = resources.getConfiguration();
    configuration.locale = locale;
    resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
    return context;
}
```

I also try to add this but nothing happened

```
@Override
public void applyOverrideConfiguration(Configuration overrideConfiguration) {
    if (overrideConfiguration != null) {
        int uiMode = overrideConfiguration.uiMode;
        overrideConfiguration.setTo(getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration());
        overrideConfiguration.uiMode = uiMode;

    }
    super.applyOverrideConfiguration(overrideConfiguration);
}
```

and I change theme like this `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)`

Comment: did you fix the issue?